# Redundant store in JIT disassemble

Tags: assembly, jvm, reverse-engineering, jit, jvm-hotspot

I continue to explore a JIT assemble output and I found a pair of strange load/store instructions:

```
mov    0x30(%rsp),%rdx ; <---- this load 

test   %edi,%edi
jne    0x00007fd3d27c5032

cmp    %r11d,%r10d
jae    0x00007fd3d27c4fbc
mov    0x10(%rbx,%r10,4),%edi
test   %edi,%edi
je     0x00007fd3d27c5062

mov    0xc(%rbp),%esi
test   %esi,%esi
je     0x00007fd3d27c4fea
mov    %r8d,0x1c(%rsp)
mov    %rdx,0x30(%rsp) ; <---- this store 

mov    %rax,0x28(%rsp)
mov    %ecx,0x10(%rsp)
mov    %rbp,0x20(%rsp)
mov    %rbx,0x8(%rsp)
mov    %r13d,%ebp
mov    %r10d,0x14(%rsp)
mov    %r11d,0x18(%rsp)
mov    %r14d,0x40(%rsp)
mov    %r9,(%rsp)
lea    (%r12,%rdi,8),%rdx

shl    $0x3,%rsi
callq  0x00007fd3caceaf00



mov    0x20(%rsp),%r11
mov    0x10(%r11),%r10d


mov    0x8(%r12,%r10,8),%r8d
cmp    $0xf2c10,%r8d
jne    0x00007fd3d27c4ffa

lea    (%r12,%r10,8),%r8

mov    0x10(%r8),%r10
movabs $0x7fffffffffffffff,%r9
cmp    %r9,%r10
je     0x00007fd3d27c5092

mov    %r10,%rdx
add    $0x1,%rdx

test   %rdx,%rdx
jle    0x00007fd3d27c50ce
mov    %r10,%rax
lock cmpxchg %rdx,0x10(%r8)
sete   %r11b
movzbl %r11b,%r11d

test   %r11d,%r11d
je     0x00007fd3d27c5116
test   %r10,%r10
jle    0x00007fd3d27c4f48



mov    0x108(%r15),%r11
mov    0x14(%rsp),%r10d
inc    %r10d

mov    0x1c(%rsp),%r8d
inc    %r8d
test   %eax,(%r11)


mov    (%rsp),%r9
mov    0x40(%rsp),%r14d
mov    0x18(%rsp),%r11d
mov    %ebp,%r13d
mov    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
mov    0x20(%rsp),%rbp
mov    0x10(%rsp),%ecx
mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax

movzbl 0x18(%r9),%edi
movslq %r8d,%rsi

cmp    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
jge    0x00007fd3d27c4f17

cmp    %r11d,%r10d
jl     0x00007fd3d27c4dea    ; this is the end of the loop
                             ; jump to the first instruction in this listing
```

Why are these instructions needed? There is no work with `%rdx` between the load/store. Yes, this is a loop, but I don't see why it might be useful on the next iterations neither.

Is it a bug or is it the same sort of [JVM tricks](https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/22-safepoint-polls/#_practice) as in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054782/useless-test-instruction)?

I've found the same problem in [this article](https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/1-lock-coarsening-for-loops/) but there is no explanation there.

The full PrintAssemble you might see [here](https://github.com/QIvan/reactive-hardcore/blob/master/result.txt#L78) and the original code is [here](https://github.com/QIvan/reactive-hardcore/blob/master/src/jmh/java/org/test/reactive/ArrayPublisher.java#L140)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there are no branch targets anywhere in those blocks?  If not, then yeah it looks like a missed optimization, but those are not rare in JITed code.  This one looks easy for a compiler to spot, though, again *if* there's no way anything else can branch into any of the basic blocks after the load, and *if* the compiler can easily prove that.

Comment: It's not the full body of nmethod. Can you post the complete PrintAssembly output, including stubs?

Comment: i think no, at least perfasm didn't show me them... Here it draws arrows for jums https://github.com/QIvan/reactive-hardcore/blob/master/result.txt#L83

Comment: perfasm shows only *hottest* regions. This does not yet mean there is no inbound branch from somewhere else (e.g. from a stub).

Comment: sorry that stubs do you mean? This is full output of run jmh with "perfasm" key https://github.com/QIvan/reactive-hardcore/blob/master/result.txt

Comment: ok i'll try to print it out and add to the repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reproduced the [full assembly code](https://gist.github.com/apangin/e27c5f2b68c27f4d6973d6361f992096) for `ArraySubscription.slowPath`. Though the register mapping is slightly different comparing to your snippet, the code structure is exactly the same.

The incomplete fragment led you to a wrong conclusion. Actually `%rdx` **can** change between load and store, because there is a branch target in the middle: [L219](https://gist.github.com/apangin/e27c5f2b68c27f4d6973d6361f992096#file-slowpath-asm-L219) -> [L55](https://gist.github.com/apangin/e27c5f2b68c27f4d6973d6361f992096#file-slowpath-asm-L55)

This becomes quite understandable when looking at the corresponding [Java source code](https://github.com/QIvan/reactive-hardcore/blob/master/src/jmh/java/org/test/reactive/ArrayPublisher.java#L94):

```
        while (true) {
            for (; sent < n && idx < length; sent++, idx++) {
                if (canceled) {
                    return;
                }

                T element = array[idx];

                if (element == null) {
                    subscriber.onError(new NullPointerException());
                    return;
                }

                subscriber.onNext(element);
            }
```

Perfasm showed you the compiled code for the hot inner `for` loop. The value at `0x30(%rsp)`, which is also cached in `%rdx`, holds the local variable `n`. But then, after the loop, the value of `n` changes:

```
            n = requested;
```

and the outer `while` continues. The [corresponding compiled code](https://gist.github.com/apangin/e27c5f2b68c27f4d6973d6361f992096#file-slowpath-asm-L200) updates `n` only in a register, not in `0x30(%rsp)`.

Comment: Wow! That was really awesome! I wish in some day to be able to understand an assemble code as you do ) 

Sorry, yesterday I spent some time on fighting with PrintAssemble output in jmh (additional thank you for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293812/2406992) and when i've got the full assembly code https://github.com/QIvan/reactive-hardcore/blob/master/result_printAssembly.txt was too late and I wanted to explore it myself first. 

Aaand... today I got the same results as you did and get here to write that I was idiot... 
Anyway many thanks for your answer!

Comment: btw how did you print assebly code in INTEL syntax instead of AT&T?

Comment: @QIvan [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337670/hotspot7-hsdis-printassembly-intel-syntax)